# Formula to calculate MAX from strings

Tags: string, excel, excel-formula, max, min

I have a number of cells with week numbers listed in a column, eg:

```
A1 = Wk01
A2 = Wk02
A3 = Wk09
A4 = Wk32
A5 = Wk24
```

I would like to extract MIN and MAX week.

Could you suggest a formula?:

A10 = MAX_Formula (A1:A5) = `Wk32`

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler to strip out the "Wk" part of the week number data and then just use a Max () function on the remaining, numeric information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this "array formula" in A10

`="Wk"&MAX((0&SUBSTITUTE(A1:A5,"Wk",""))+0)`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

That uses `SUBSTITUTE` function to strip the "Wk" part from each cell so that `MAX` can determine the highest number - This also works if some of the cells are empty

You can do the same for `MIN` but if you have any blanks in the range you'll get `Wk0` so to avoid that use this version for `MIN`

`="Wk"&MIN(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A5,"Wk","")+0,""))`

also confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: @pnuts - thanks - I suppose you could use `RIGHT` here, is that the way? - Re FREQUENCY - that's a different question, right? I didn't know that - do you know if {B5:B50;J5:N50} or similar works with other functions in google?

Comment: OK, thanks - `TTEST` is an interesting one because it **doesn't** work with "union" arguments in Excel.....